# In grid, what does 2/-2 means?

Tags: html, css

I have seen someone used grid-column: 1/-1 and he explained that instead to write
1/(the number of the last grid), you simply can use 1/-1 .
But then i have seen he also used 2/-2,
i thought it means start from grid 2 till the end, but it didnt it has spanned like 2/4.
so what does 2/-2 means?

Comment: This is a question that, really, should be answered by looking at documentation, such as MDN's: [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the MDN documentation:

> If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid.

So as you can see in the below example the `grid-column: 2 / -2;` will spread the element over all columns except the first and last.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

#nr1 {
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="nr1" class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div id="nr2" class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div id="nr3" class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div id="nr4" class="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its like the column grid number looks like that?

grid-template-columns: auto(-5) auto (-4)auto(-3)200px(-2) auto(-1);
grid-template-columns: (1)auto (2)150px(3) auto (4)auto(5) auto;

So when i say  grid-column: 2/-2, it looks where is the 2 located on the "positive" axis and where the -2 is located on the "negative" axis, so here it will be from column 150px up until the column with 200px, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

A self-explanatory example:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(6,1fr);
  grid-gap:10px;
}

i {
  background:red;
  height:20px;
}

.grid > div {
  border:2px solid;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
  <div style="grid-column:1/-1">
    from the 1st to the last
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column:2/-2">
    from the 2nd to the "before the last" 
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column:3/-3">
    from the 3rd to the 3rd starting from the end 
  </div>
</div>
```